# Bind Textbox to Listview GridViewColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I am looking to bind a single text box to the value found in a gridviewcolumn.
However, when edititng the textbox i want it to also edit and update the grid view column row that i have selected.

XAML

```
<ListView x:Name="ExampleLV" ItemsSource="{Binding Data.Collection}">    
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="ColumnName1" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Value[0], Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="ColumnName2" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Value[1], Mode=TwoWay}"/>  
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>

<TextBox Name="ExampleTB1" Text="{Binding ElementName=ExampleLV, Path=SelectedItem.Values[0]}"/>
<TextBox Name="ExampleTB2" Text="{Binding ElementName=ExampleLV, Path=SelectedItem.Values[1]}"/>
```

C# - The Collection is mapped to a string array

```
Collection.Add(new ListViewItem() { Values = new string[] { "abc", "123" } });
```

The ListViewItem is a custom class I have built.

```
public class ListViewItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string[] _values;

        #region Properties

        public string[] Values
        {
            get { return _values; }
            set
            {
                if (value == _values) return;
                _values = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        #endregion

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;//[NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

The problem I am having is that the Values are being updated for the textbox, but they arn't updating the listviewItem.  However the values being stored are updating just not the GridViewColumn.

I also want this working with a combobox.  Please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things..

You are updating the string within the collection, so you'll need to implement INotify on the collection items.

Something like:

```
public class ValueViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _value;

    public string Value
    {
        get { return _values; }
        set
        {
            if (_value == value) return;

            _value = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Update your ListViewItem ViewModel to use the new ValueViewModel type.

```
public class ListViewItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ValueViewModel[] _values;

    #region Properties

    public ValueViewModel[] Values
    {
        get { return _values; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _values) return;
            _values = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    #endregion

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;//[NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Lastly, update your bindings:

```
<ListView x:Name="ExampleLV" ItemsSource="{Binding Data.Collection}"> 

    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="ColumnName1" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Value[0].Value, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="ColumnName2" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Value[1].Value, Mode=TwoWay}"/>  
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View> </ListView>

<TextBox Name="ExampleTB1" Text="{Binding ElementName=ExampleLV, Path=SelectedItem.Values[0].Value}"/> <TextBox Name="ExampleTB2" Text="{Binding ElementName=ExampleLV, Path=SelectedItem.Values[1].Value}"/>
```

Comment: Aye, thanks to @mm8 I implemented this, and it makes sense however its still not matching the values at real time. Only on item click.

Comment: I should be more clear, its now updating but on focus exit. Is it possible to update on keypress instead?

Comment: EDIT: UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged solves this. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, by default TextBox controls only update upon lose focus. Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 1):

You are binding to a `string` and since the `String` class doesn't implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface the target properties (columns) won't be updated.

Instead of binding to an item in a `string` array (`Value[0]` and `Value[1]`), you should bind to a property of a class that implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

So change type of the `Values` property from `string[]` to a type that has two properties that raise change notifications and bind to these properties instead of binding to the `string` array.